# Laravel Schema::drop($table) return value

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-migrations

I was just wondering if I use drop() method in Laravel Eloquent like say,

```
    Schema::drop('users')
```

what will be the return value of it ? 
Though I can use hasTable() method after drop() method to check table existence but I was just wondering if we can get it directly from return value ?

In laravel api Blueprintclass I can see it's mentioned as Return Value - Fluent. But I don't know what is the meaning of it ? 
Can anyone help ?

Thanks in advance,

Sambhav

Comment: Did you experience it what it returns?

Comment: Hi Basheer, Yes it throws an exception if table doesn't exist, though I didn't check specifically what it returns...I tried putting it under if condition but result wasn't desirable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can look at `Illuminate\Database\Schema\Builder.php` source. As you see:

```
public function drop($table)
{
        $blueprint = $this->createBlueprint($table);

        $blueprint->drop();

        $this->build($blueprint);
}
```

doesn't return any value.

The question is what you want to check. If drop is successful nothing happens and in case of any error, probably Exception will be thrown.

Comment: Hi Marcin,ok then it's fine if it don't return anything, I was just wondering if it returns anything then I can check directly the return value...Ok as you said I will put exception handling, thank you for the quick response.